# Should I test the whole return of a function or only a sample?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, web-scraping

I want to test the return of a script that queries a list of urls (more than 1000), extracts some data from the response and returns it as an array of objects (dict) with certain attributes.
Is it safe to test only a sample from the returned list ?
My concern is mainly that exhaustive testing would be time consuming.

P.S. I am hoping that a random sampling would help catch errors, knowing that the response bodies of the urls my script queries may be inconsistant.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question such that you actually access the urls in the list.  In unit-testing, you would normally take a different approach (but not in integration-testing, see the bottom of my answer).  You would not actually access those urls, but instead find some way to "simulate" the url access.  As part of this simulated url access, your tests can also define what the responses look like.

This way, you can test all aspects of your code that handles the responses.  You can simulate all kinds of valid, but also as you mention inconsistent responses - because you have full control from the tests.

There are several ways to make it possible for your tests to "simulate" that url access: One option is, to separate within your code the part that does the url access from the part that processes the response.  In pseudo-code:

```
response = accessUrl(url);
handleResponse(response);
```

Then, in unit-testing you would focus on testing the function `handleResponse`, and test the rest of the code in integration-testing.

A second option is to mock the function/method that performs the url access.  This makes sense if it is difficult to change the code to achieve the separation I have shown in the pseudo-code.  There are lots of information about mocking available on the web.

In any case, this way of testing allows you to test the functionality of your code more systematically.  You can test all scenarios you are aware of and will be sure that these were really covered because you have full control.

The testing approach you have described is more on the level of integration testing, and also makes sense *after you have fully unit-tested your code*: Because, after all, you may still have missed some real-world scenarios that your code should handle.

Comment: thank you for your answer, my approach right now is: 1/ Query all the urls and write them into a file (this script runs once or twice a day) 2/ Test using the data in the file (little bit faster) 3/ Breaking up my code, one problem I had is that I had functions that do too much (thus difficult to unit test, without testing something else), so I will try to apply your answer.